# Executing Database Job as part of TFS Build

Tags: sql-server, tfs, msbuild, sql-server-data-tools

I have a request to perform a "smoke test" for database deployments that I am doing within TFS. I would like to be able to Execute a database job after deployment in TFS that would be used to populate data. After that, the possibility to run some SQL statements with results of how many records were inserted, things like that.

I have looked into Unit Testing with SSDT, but was wondering if there are any other options (plus it seems you can only kick off SPROCs with that method).

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: There's always the option to use post-deploy scripts as part of your SQL Project to populate the data. You could look into SQL Data Compare Pro from Red-Gate to populate from some known source after doing the build. There are definitely options, but it may help to clarify what you're planning to insert/update as far as data goes. If you could run into existing data to update, I'd probably investigate SQL Data Compare.

Comment: The job would only be ran in lower environments where we are dropping/creating a DB after every deploy, so it would be mostly inserts.

Comment: How are you deploying the db? Are you using dacpac?

Comment: In that case, I'd either script out the inserts to run as a post-deploy script or another process or run a SQL Data Compare job against a "good" source. (maybe a read-only DB so nobody accidentally makes changes to it) May also want to consider a "New" publish profile to differentiate whether or not you'll update/populate tables in post-deploy scripts.

Comment: The DB is being deployed through a dacpac yes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have a SSDT project and you're using the DACPAC to deploy as part of you build, and you are just wondering how to include the population of data as part of the deploy.  What I usually do is just use a post-deploy script with a whole bunch of INSERT's (I typically split it up into separate files with INSERT's for each table, then include these in the main post-deploy script using the :r syntax).  To generate the insert scripts I'll usually use the functionality in SSMS to script out a database, and in the advanced options just tell it to script data-only, then copy paste that into my post-deploy script.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would use either sqlcmd EXEC tasks, but probably (more likely) this sqlcmd-msbuild task.

http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/help/4.0.5.0/html/3b72c130-7fc9-8b8a-132c-62999e5b1183.htm

You can have INSERT scripts.

You could also incorporate some 'unit testing' methods that Andy Leonard discusses.

http://www.dotnetrocks.com/default.aspx?showNum=312

Comment: Do you you have a good example of doing this? I wrote a SPROC that kicks off the job, and watches the job activity until it is complete (basically wrapping an ASYNC SPROC call) and I want to call the SPROC from MSBuild, and wait for it to return. The SPROC can take up to 10 minutes to complete.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you do not do this as part of a build.

You want your build to be fast and that likely means that you do not have not should you need an instance of your application. You should use a release management tool to deploy your application to an environment and them run instance tests there.

You can use RM for Visual Studio 2013 to create a release pipeline that does this. These tools contain drag an drop elements for creating and updating databases.

http://nakedalm.com/building-release-pipeline-release-management-visual-studio-2013/

Comment: We have already plugged in Deployment through TFS using PowerShell and WindowsRM (Visual Studio 2012). Since we have this entire system already in place, and all we want is an easy way to populate data when we deploy to our lower environments.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [tSQLt](http://tsqlt.org/)? tSQLt is open source and probably the most-used SQL Server unit test framework available. To use it correctly you'd insert the data within the test itself (INSERTs). This is a particularly cunning way of dealing with test set up, as tSQLt rolls back the transaction after the test has run, bringing your test environment back to a known state.